# Connect PhpStorm to remote docker container

Tags: docker, phpstorm

Is possible to browse and edit files with PHP in a remote container? The files are inside the container.

Sometimes I need to test something on a remote container. I can connect with SSH and then go to the container - and use Nano to edit. It would be great if I can see files in PhpStorm remote hosts - like se files outside container.

Comment: Why have you included the message from the quality filter instead of following its advice?

Comment: i dont have example code, question is simple - i try google but without results. so what i can write more?

Comment: For starters, what kind of container, where is it located, what are you trying to achieve. To me it seems an odd requirement to want to edit files in a remote container (generally you'd edit the files in your favourite version control system, trigger a new build and deploy the new image). However, if I needed to do that, I would sooner think of a solution just like doing that on any other remote system (Docker based or otherwise): using something like SSH, or maybe SFTP. or rsync, etc.

Comment: i update desc - now its ok ?

Comment: Usually files are mounted into the container locally, and when you have finished your dev, you are committing and running the pipeline to build your image and push it. Pushing files remotely is not a good idea, what if another dev join your team and need to push to the same remote host ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Connect to a remote server from PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-development-starting-page.html)

Comment: I undestand and this is normal flow, but when i have problem only on prod , its very helpfull to test some solutions - now i edit with nano but this is not usefully - that is reason why I use phpstorm. so question is can I (i dont know) make ssh tunel to container and open it like remote connection. (to remote server we can easy connect and edit files- but files is in remote server in container)

Comment: Currently, it is possible to open files from the container in read-only mode only. Here is a ticket similar to your scenario: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176736

Comment: i dont have readonly mode-  when i open local ssh connection to container i can edit all files. So this is like 2 ssh connections 1 to host , 2 to container